# PHP - Objeto array dentro de una clase

Tags: php, poo

Ando perdido con la POO y PHP.

Debo crear una clase llamada Catálogo que almacene un conjunto de objetos Películas en un array.
Cada array estará formada por los atributos: ID, nombre y director.

```
<?php 

    class Catalogo {

    public $pelicula = array();

    }
```

##########

```
<?php 

include("catalogo.php");


$film1 = new Catalogo;

$film1 = new Pelicula ('1', 'Celda 211','Daniel Monzón' );
$film2 = new Pelicula ('2', 'Los lunes al sol','Fernando León de Aranoa' );
```

Como veis soy muy novato en el tema de la POO,

Muchas gracias

Comment: Por otro lado si estamos hablando de la clase catálogos, ¿de donde salió la clase Pelicula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te hago los siguientes comentarios:

- Me parece que el planteamiento no es el adecuado
- La clase sobre la que inicialmente deberías estar trabajando es `Pelicula`

  - Con todas sus propiedades y métodos inherentes
- Cada que instancies y *registres* una nueva película en un objeto determinado, la tendrás a disposición para manipularla
- Dentro de la clase `Pelicula` puedes tener un método que *almacene* todas las películas que se van creando dentro de un array
- Cuando imprimas el retorno de dicho método entonces estarías visualizando *el catálogo* de películas deseadas

**Ejemplo**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

class Pelicula
{
    public array $catalogoPeliculas;

    public function __construct(public string|null $tituloPelicula = NULL, public string|null $fechaEstrenoPelicula = NULL)
    {}

    public function catalogoPeliculas(Pelicula ...$peliculaAgregada): array
    {
        return $this->catalogoPeliculas[] = $peliculaAgregada;
    }
}

$peliculaUno  = new Pelicula('pelicula 1', "2016-01-19");
$peliculaDos  = new Pelicula('pelicula 2', "2017-01-19");
$peliculaTres = new Pelicula('pelicula 3', "2018-01-19");



print_r((new Pelicula())->catalogoPeliculas($peliculaUno, $peliculaDos, $peliculaTres));
```

Que daría una salida como esta:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Pelicula Object
        (
            [tituloPelicula] => pelicula 1
            [fechaEstrenoPelicula] => 2016-01-19
        )

    [1] => Pelicula Object
        (
            [tituloPelicula] => pelicula 2
            [fechaEstrenoPelicula] => 2017-01-19
        )

    [2] => Pelicula Object
        (
            [tituloPelicula] => pelicula 3
            [fechaEstrenoPelicula] => 2018-01-19
        )

)
```

Comentarios finales:

- **Importante** esto solo busca ser una ejemplificación práctica, pero claramente hacen falta propiedades y métodos...
- La sintaxis de este ejemplo esta apoyada en PHP 8 para el caso del método constructor, pero sin problema lo puedes trasladar a la sintaxis regular
- Además recomiendo en el mismo enlace revisar la sección de **Union Types**
- Ya que la salida que buscas es el conjunto de películas dentro de un *array* entonces pase como parámetro a `$peliculaAgregada` precedido de `...` para poder trabajar con un número dinámico de argumentos

**Fuentes de consulta extra**

- [Funciones variadicas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics)
- [Declaración de tipos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)
- [Constructor property promotion PHP8](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#constructor-property-promotion)
- [Declaraciones de tipo de devolución](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations)

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero

Comment: Disculpa, como debo hacerlo?

Answer (score 3):

Estoy viendo errores en tu código:

- primero acostúmbrate a no utilizar propiedades publicas, a no ser que sea para un caso muy especial. Recomendado utilizar `protected` o `private` segun el caso lo amerite.
- Segundo, no se porque estas instanciando peliculas, **vos lo que tenes que hacer es darle un valor a peliculas no instanciarla**, lo unico que debes instanciar es el objeto catalogo

catalogo.php

```
    <?php

      class Catalogo
      {

        public $pelicula;
      }

    ?>
```

index.php

```
<?php

require_once 'catalogo.php';

$film1 = new Catalogo();
$film1->pelicula = [1, 'madmax'];

$film2 = new Catalogo();
$film2->pelicula = [2, 'spider-man'];

var_dump($film1);
var_dump($film2);
```

Comment: creo que lo que busca hacer es algo como: 
`$film['indice_nombre_de_la_peli']->dato1();` luego 
`$film['indice_nombre_de_la_peli']->dato2();` luego 
`$film['indice_nombre_de_la_peli']->dato3();`